# Knockout: HTML table displaying additional information

Tags: knockout.js, html-table

I am stuck with an issue which I believe is simple, but somehow not able to resolve.
I have an simple HTML table which displays list of employees. The last column of this table has an hyperlink(called "Show Additional Information"). 
When user clicks on this link, I want to display the additional information about that particular employee just beneath his data row.
What should be the logic to display the extra  for the selected row? With my logic it is making  visible for all the rows.
We are using knockout framework.

HTML table

```
<table id="employees-data" data-bind="if: employeesList().length > 0">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: employeesList">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind ="text: $index() + 1"></td>
        <td data-bind ="text: moment(dateCreated).format('llll')"></td>
        <td data-bind ="text: empName"></td>
        <td data-bind ="text: empBirthDate"></td>
        <td data-bind ="text: empCity"></td>
        <td><a data-bind="ifnot: additionalInfo == null, attr: { title: additionalInfo},
               click: $parent.toggleAdditionalInfoDisplay">Show Additional Information</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan="6" data-bind="visible: $parent.showAdditionalInfo, text: additionalInfo"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JS file:

```
self.showAdditionalInfo = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleAdditionalInfoDisplay = function() {
        self.showAdditionalInfo(!self.showAdditionalInfo());
        alert('showRow is now ' + self.showAdditionalInfo());
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `knockout mapping` plugin to create an employee with a property to handle the `visible` binding just for that row.

Let's say you have data coming from server in the following fashion -

```
var dataFromServer = [{
    name: "abc",
    id: 123,
    gender: "female",
    favoriteFood: "Sphagetti"
  }, {
    name: "xyz",
    id: 456,
    gender: "male",
    favoriteFood: "Pasta"
}];
```

Now, you would go about creating an `Employee` from the mapping plug in like so -

```
    var mappingOptions = {
    create: function(options) {
      return new Employees(options.data);
    }
  };

  self.employees = ko.observableArray([]);

  function Employees(data) {
    var self = this;
    if (data !== null) {
      self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
      self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
      self.ifShowAdditionalInformation = ko.observable(false);
      self.favoriteFood = ko.observable(data.favoriteFood);
      self.additionalInfo = "My favorite food is " + self.favoriteFood();
      self.toggleAdditionalInfoDisplay = function() {
        self.ifShowAdditionalInformation(!self.ifShowAdditionalInformation());
      }
    }
  }

  var mappedEmployees = ko.mapping.fromJS(dataFromServer, mappingOptions);

  self.employees(mappedEmployees());
```

As you can notice, how this gives you more control over individual rows. The `toggleAdditionalInfoDisplay` is fired only for that row which is being clicked leaving others unaffected. Also, the `ifShowAdditionalInformation` controls the visibility of the row it is part of.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbhuez1a/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But resolved this by writing one custom JS function. Though, the solution provided by you is better, but it was just that I didn't have liberty to modify my VM (that is controlled by some other component)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by below JS method:

```
self.showAdditionalInfo = ko.observable(false);
self.additionalInfoLinkIndex = ko.observable(false);

self.toggleAdditionalInfoDisplay = function(data, event) {
            //get the id of clicked link
            var clickedElementId = event.target.id;

            //if additional info view is already open, showAdditionalInfo is true
            if(self.showAdditionalInfo()) {
                //If current open item index is same as clickedElement index,
                 //then close the view
                if(self.additionalInfoLinkIndex() == clickedElementId) {
                    self.showAdditionalInfo(false);
                    return;
                }
            }
            self.additionalInfoLinkIndex(clickedElementId);
            self.showAdditionalInfo(true);
        };
```

HTML:

Show Additional Info Link

```
<td>
          <a style="cursor:pointer;" id="$index()"
            data-bind="ifnot: additionalInfo == null,
            attr: { id: $index(),
            title: additionalInfo}, click: $parent.toggleAdditionalInfoDisplay">View
          </a>
        </td>
```

Row to display additional info

```
<tr>
<td colspan="6" data-bind="visible: $parent.showAdditionalInfo() && $parent.additionalInfoLinkIndex() == $index()">
    <pre data-bind="text: additionalInfo"></pre>
</td>
</tr>
```